# Stopping auto-scrolling to bottom of listbox

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I am using Telerik's RadGridView within a UserControl to display a list of messages received from an XMPP server. I have been able to set it so that when I receive a message I can scroll to the bottom of the list with something like this:

```
private GridViewScrollViewer scrollViewer;

void controller_OnMessageReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewer = receivedMessageList.ChildrenOfType<GridViewScrollViewer>().FirstOrDefault();
    scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
}
```

However what I want to be able to do is disable the auto scrolling when the user uses the scroll bar and then re-enable it when he scrolls to the bottom of the list. I thought I could attach to the `ScrollChanged` event but that doesn't seem to hold enough information for me to use.

As a slight addition to this in the `Loaded` event of the control, and the RadGridView the scrollViewer call I have above comes as null. I thought that once the control was Loaded that all UI elements are ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the null scrollViewer variable, I guess when you load the control, the scrollViewer is not shown since there is nothing in it yet. Try setting:

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
```

In your XAML

Now for the actual problem:
You could monitor the `HorizontalOffset` and the `VerticalOffset` of the scrollviewer:

Create two `Double` fields in your class to store them and then, before calling `ScrollToBottom()`, compare the current values to the ones saved. 
If the user manually moved the scrollbars, the values will be different and you don't scroll, otherwise you `ScrollToBottom()`.

Comment: Changing the scroll viewer to visible doesn't help. I am sure there is something in the way the control has been created that is causing it. Will track it down eventually I suspect. Monitoring the offset sounds like it might well be a way to do it, however when the size of the window changes or the listbox also then the offset changes so I guess it might involve monitoring in a variety of places. But it's a place to start I guess :-)